# GestureDetectorCompact not working?

Tags: android, gesturedetector

My code

```
 public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        gestureDetectorCompat.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm debugging every method, but none get's called.
Where i'm wrong?

Comment: It's working fine in my case with `onTouchEvent(....)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GestureDetectorCompat` is not called automatically. You have to override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in your `Activity`, and pass the event to the gesture detector. E.g.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)). Please refer to it, for the meaning of the returning value.

Comment: Any idea about why I wouldn't be receiving even calls to onTouchEvent or to the rest of events having called to the gestureDetectorCompat? @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your code. It's mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).

```
@Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```